# Lotus Notes Source Control

Tags: git, version-control, lotus-notes

I know that Git is recommended for source control with XPages development but for older Lotus Notes applications, specifically ones with lots of forms, what is the best choice for source control - Git or Teamstudio CIAO ?

Comment: Git essentially snapshots your filesystem.  The files can be text or binary.  If you have binary blobs you may need to tell git not to adjust them.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Git can store binary blobs but they are hard to merge. So git is *mostly* oriented towards storing and merging text files.

Comment: @phd It does not make sense to merge binary blobs.  How would you merge two versions of a word file?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That's exactly why git is not suitable to store a lot of binary files in branches. git is oriented towards storing text files.

Comment: @phd git is great for _storing_ a lot of binary files.

Comment: @Thorbjørn It makes no less sense to merge MS Word files than to merge text files, and in fact, Git supports using custom merge drivers for different file types to do exactly this. See https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser naturally, but the binary formats of word and lotus notes mean you cannot use ANY of the usual tools of the trade but need new, custom made tools made. How will you visualize a diff for instance?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Lots of commercial tools (such as Araxis Merge) claim to be able to visualize diffs in MS Word files, as does Word itself. I don’t use MS Office, so I’ve never tested these tools, but they do already exist (at least for some popular binary formats) without having to do custom development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [Teamstudio CIAO](https://www.teamstudio.com/ciao/). Reasons as below:

1. Git is not good at version control for binary files and the binary files will expanded git repo size quickly. Even you can git git LFS, but it’s more convenient to use teamstudio CIAO.
2. Teamstudio is the VCS design for IBM Notes (and Domino). And you can use the integrate GUI to trace versions easily

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to put entire templates under source control as a unit, any solution will do. If you want to be able to put individual design elements under source control, I think TeamStudio CIAO is the only game in town. (There was one other, but I don't think it's still supported and I don't recall the name.)

One alternative that I toyed with years ago was doing DXL exports to create text files for individual design elements that could be put under source control, but it was very cumbersome and we never got very far with it.